# F# - convert time in microsecond to day of the week

Tags: f#

I am trying to learn F# and was wondering if i have a json object which has time in microseconds as int. I want to get the day, date and time out of this and was wondering how to do it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert microseconds into a timestamp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744375/how-do-i-convert-microseconds-into-a-timestamp)

Answer (score 2):

I actually happen to have needed to do this recently. You'll almost certainly want to use the .NET time objects (DateTime, DateTimeOffset, TimeSpan) in some capacity. Here's what I went with:

```
let TicksPerMicrosecond =
    TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond / 1000L

let FromUnixTimeMicroseconds (us: int64) =
    DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds 0L + TimeSpan.FromTicks(us * TicksPerMicrosecond)
```

From `TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond` we can calculate how many are in a microsecond (if I remember correctly it's 10, but this way it doesn't seem as "magic"). Then I can convert the microseconds value into ticks and add it to the epoch date.

To get the day of the week (assuming the time zone is UTC), you'd just use [`DateTimeOffset.DayOfWeek`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.dayofweek).